# Nested if in for loop appears to use all results instead of single one

Tags: linux, shell, curl, sh

I'm not sure if this is a `curl` issue or if it's an issue with my code.
I am uploading a directory's content to a remote server using `curl -T` and since `curl` does not, according to the help file and some googling, have a way to skip file if it exists I am trying to script around it.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /foo/bar
curl --user foo:bar -ls ftp://ftp.server.foo/remote/dir/ > /foo/bar/temp.txt
for file in ./*.dat
do
    if ! grep -Fq "$file" temp.txt
    then
        curl --user foo:bar -T "$file" ftp://ftp.server.foo/remote/dir/
    fi
done
rm -f /foo/bar/temp.txt
```

I currently have 6 files in `/foo/bar` and those are uploaded to remote already. I removed one of the files from remote for testing purposes, but all 6 files were transferred anew.

Using the code above, as long as there is a not-match against temp.txt, `curl` uploads ALL files that's found in the `for` loop, regardless if it matches the `if` condition or not. Am I missing something royally obvious or this a `curl` thing and I'm better off over in SuperUser?

Comment: What do you see when you run `sh -x your.script.sh`?  Is the trouble that you grep `temp.txt` but create `/foo/bar/temp.txt`?  Hmmm; you do `cd /foo/bar` so the path in the `curl` command redirection is unnecessary.  Have you looked in `/foo/bar/temp.txt` to check what is in it?

Comment: For the first question, I see continous `grep` commands and for every `grep` there is a `curl` call also. I did however notice now, thanks to your suggestion, that the `grep` command is looking for `./file1.dat` specifically, instead of just `file1.dat` - I will try doing simply `for file in *.dat` and update you with results. 

For second question, the `temp.txt` file contains `.`, `..`, `file1.dat`, `file2.dat`, `file3.dat` and so on.

Comment: So now you know why `grep` isn't finding the name (file, string) it is looking for in `temp.txt`, and therefore it fails and the `curl` command in the loop is executed for each file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comment from [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) I found via `sh -x script.sh` that my `for` statement was the issue. The way I had written it, it sent `./file1.dat` to `grep` to try to find in `temp.txt`, which only had `file1.dat` and **not** `./file1.dat` specifically.

Changed to `for file in *.dat` and this fixed the issue.